# Tensorflow C++ Object detection(video)

Tags: tensorflow, object-detection

its my first question in stackoverflow however 
my Question how i can use my already trained frozen_graph and label_map from python object detection and use that in my c++ object detection.

i used python for object detection in a video and it wasnt so fast at all 25 fps with mss.sct() and multithreaded

so i want to try it in c++ cause i know that there are more possible and heared that python is little slow.

Someone has an object detection example for an image in c++ or c# ?

Would be awesome

Comment: HI, you might find this of interest https://github.com/lysukhin/tensorflow-object-detection-cpp

Comment: Thank you for the info  i must figure out how to grab the desktop screen and then i try to set it up 

Comment: Can i use c++ in 32bit version for tensorflow?? or only 64bit

Answer (score 0):

Check https://medium.com/jim-fleming/loading-a-tensorflow-graph-with-the-c-api-4caaff88463f,

and you need to build C++ API like https://joe-antognini.github.io/machine-learning/build-windows-tf